# Updates with a script ElasticSearch API not accepting Scala Map

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I came across a use-case where I need to update a specific field in the ElasticSearch document. So for this use-case, I have used the `Update API with a script` [ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update.html#_updates_with_a_script). But I faced an issue(compilation error) with `Script` Constructor which accepts the following parameters:--> `type`, `lang`, `idOrCode` and `params` and the issue was with `params`(java.util.Map) parameter.

I have even tried the Scala to Java converters but could not solve it.

**Code snippet**

```scala
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions
import org.elasticsearch.script.{Script, ScriptType}

object Testing extends App {

  val result = updateByScript("testing", "hW7BBnQBn2nWmIjS_b0C", 10.0)
  println("@@@@@@result:---> " + result)
  high_level_client.close()

  def updateByScript(index: String, id: String, count: Double) = {

    //import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap
    //import collection.JavaConverters._
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

    val updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, id)
    
    val params = Map[String, Double]("count" -> count)

    val script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.count += params.count", mapAsJavaMap(params))
    updateRequest.script(script)

    high_level_client.update(updateRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above issue, I have tried the `Script` Constructor with the `idOrCode` parameter and which solved my use-case but still I did not get the solution for other `Script` Constructors.

Working code with Constructor which accept `idOrCode` parameter.

**Code snippet**

```scala
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions
import org.elasticsearch.script.{Script, ScriptType}

object Testing extends App {

  val result = updateByScript("testing", "hW7BBnQBn2nWmIjS_b0C", 10.0)
  println("@@@@@@result:---> " + result)
  high_level_client.close()

  def updateByScript(index: String, id: String, count: Double) = {
    val updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, id)
    val script = new Script(s"""ctx._source.count += $count""")
    updateRequest.script(script)
    high_level_client.update(updateRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
  }
}
```